# G_LOCK behavior changed from glib 2.46 to glib 2.48?

Tags: c++, multithreading, glib, ubuntu-16.04

I'm looking at a piece of code, which did work until recently. Basically, I have a C++ class, in which I protect a variable with a G_LOCK_DEFINE macro.

```
class CSomeClass {
private:
    gulong mSomeCounter;
    G_LOCK_DEFINE(mSomeCounter);

public:
    CSomeClass ();
}
```

The constructor is implemented in a separate .cpp file.

```
CSomeClass::CSomeClass()
{
    G_LOCK(mSomeCounter);
    mSomeCounter = 0;
    G_UNLOCK(mSomeCounter);
}
```

This variable is accessed in several functions, but the principle is always the same. Now, as already said, the code compiles fine and in fact did also run flawlessly in the past. Now, since recently, I'm getting a deadlock, whenever I come across a G_LOCK command. For debugging, I already restricted the program to just one thread, to exclude logical errors.

I did update to Ubuntu 16.04 beta recently, which pushed my glib version to 2.48.0-1ubuntu4. I already checked the changelog for relevant information on G_LOCK, but couldn't find anything. Did anybody else notice funny effects, when using G_LOCK macros with the recent glib version? Did I miss some changes here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, all that `G_LOCK_DEFINE` does is create a `GMutex` variable, who's name encodes the name of the variable that it's protecting e.g. `G_LOCK_DEFINE(mSomeCounter)` becomes `GMutex g__mSomeCounter_lock;`. So we can expand your code to something like:

```
class CSomeClass {
    private:
        gulong mSomeCounter;
        GMutex g__mSomeCounter_lock;

    public:
        CSomeClass ();
};

CSomeClass::CSomeClass()
{
    g_mutex_lock(&g__mSomeCounter_lock);
    mSomeCounter = 0;
    g_mutex_unlock(&g__mSomeCounter_lock);
}
```

The fundamental problem here is that you're not initializing **any** of the members of the class `CSomeClass`. You'll assigning values to *some* of them in the constructor, but you're definitely not initializing them. There's a difference between the assignment in braces, and using an initializer, such as:

```
    CSomeClass::CSomeClass() : mSomeCounter(0)
```

As a result, the mutex that's created, named against the variable may contain garbage. There's probably nothing in the glib code that would have changed to cause this to happen, it's more likely that changes to other libraries have changed the memory layout of you app, uncovering the bug.

The [glib documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Threads.html#g-mutex-init) hints that you need to `g_mutex_init` mutexes:

> that has been allocated on the stack, or as part of a larger structure

You don't need to `g_mutex_init` mutexes that:

> It is not necessary to initialize a mutex that has been statically allocated

Class instances are almost always **not** statically allocated.

You need to fix your constructor to ensure that it initializes the mutex 'properly' e.g.:

```
CSomeClass::CSomeClass()
{
    g_mutex_init(&G_LOCK_NAME(mSomeCounter));
    G_LOCK(mSomeCounter);
    mSomeCounter = 0;
    G_UNLOCK(mSomeCounter);
}
```

TBH, I'd put the mutex into a class holder, and initialize it as part of that, rather than the way you're doing it, to ensure that it gets initialized, locked and unlocked as part of the standard C++ RAII semantics.

If you use a small main stub, something like:

```
main() {
    { CSomeClass class1; }
    { CSomeClass class2; }
    { CSomeClass class3; }
}
```

and your code, there's a good chance it will hang anyway. (my mac crashed the example with: `GLib (gthread-posix.c): Unexpected error from C library during 'pthread_mutex_lock': Invalid argument.  Aborting.`.

some simple, example, **non production** wrappers to help with RAII:

```
class CGMutex {
    GMutex    mutex;

    public:
    CGMutex() {
        g_mutex_init(&mutex);
    }

    ~CGMutex() {
        g_mutex_clear(&mutex);
    }

    GMutex *operator&() {
        return &mutex;
    }
};

class CGMutexLocker {
    CGMutex &mRef;
    public:
    CGMutexLocker(CGMutex &mutex) : mRef(mutex) {
        g_mutex_lock(&mRef);
    }
    ~CGMutexLocker() {
        g_mutex_unlock(&mRef);
    }
};

class CSomeClass {
    private:
        gulong mSomeCounter;
        CGMutex mSomeCounterLock;

    public:
        CSomeClass ();
};

CSomeClass::CSomeClass()
{
    CGMutexLocker locker(mSomeCounterLock); // lock the mutex using the locker
    mSomeCounter = 0;
}
```

The mSomeCounter initialization ensures that the counter gets initialized, otherwise it will have garbage.